# Swift: Callback between classes using function objects and strong reference

Tags: ios, swift

I used to implement callback between classes in following ways:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var service = MyService()

    func onSomeEvent() {
        service.callback = onServiceResult
    }

    func onServiceResult(result: String) {
    }
}

class MyService {
    var callback: ((result: String) -> Void)?

    func someThingAsync() {
        //Some work being done in background thread
        //...
        //When it is done
        callback?(result: result)
    }
}
```

Later I realized that this creates strong reference cycle as MyService.callback will hold implicit self of MyViewController when I assign it onServiceResult.

Another way to implement callback that does not have reference cycle is to have delegates with week reference, but that seems to be quite verbose and too much when you just want to have one simple callback.

Is there any way in Swift to have callback as simple as the above code without reference cycle? Or if possible how to modify the above code to keep it simple and without reference cycle?

Comment: Can you pass service as a parameter to onSomeEvent?

Comment: onSomeEvent may be any method, an IBAction or any other method. Even if I pass service as parameter to onSomeEvent how will it affect as I already have reference to service in onSomeEvent as it is a data member of MyViewController.

Comment: Use delegation, or set the callback to a closure rather than a method on `MyViewController`.  But ultimately, delegation is the right answer.