# Avoiding retain cycle when using function as a block in swift

Tags: swift, block, weak-references, retain-cycle

following is a code sample you can run in a playground

```
import Foundation

class TempNotifier {  
    var onChange: (Int) -> Void = {t in }
    var currentTemp = 72

    init() {
        // 1.
        onChange = { [unowned self] temp in
            self.currentTemp = temp
        }

        // 2.
        onChange = {[unowned self] temp in
            self.tempHandler(temp)
        }

        // 3.
        unowned let s = self
        onChange = s.tempHandler
    }

    deinit {
        println("deinit")
    }

    private func tempHandler(temp: Int) {
        self.currentTemp = temp
    }
}

var tN: TempNotifier? = TempNotifier()
tN = nil
```

It illustrates 3 ways of assigning a value to a block with potential retain-cycle. Case `1.` and `2.` create no retain cycle due to `unowned self` however in case `3.` it seems like there is no way to break the retain cycle (`deinit` is never printed). As you can see, I even tried to create a local unowned reference.

Is this the desired behaviour, is it "by design"? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

*Cross-posted from https://devforums.apple.com/message/1122247*

Comment: In playground deinit() will not be called as variables are always in the scope. I asked similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329334/swift-callback-between-classes-using-function-objects-and-strong-reference. But there seems to be no way to achieve it.

Comment: Actually, if you comment out 3. deinit will be called, as for memory management, I am assigning nil to the variable explicitly - that's what causes it to deinit if there are no retain cycles

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the designed behavior.

Accessing a method without calling it, like `s.tempHandler`, is equivalent to a closure expression like `{ x in s.tempHandler(x) }`. Here `s` is not marked `unowned` or `weak`, and hence is retained by the closure. If you want it to be captured as `unowned` or `weak`, you must explicitly write out the closure.